# "nil is not a symbol" for model count in rspec matcher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd, capybara

I am trying to write an integration test where if a user clicks on a button, it creates a new record in the database (CheckPrice model).

I am running into the error `nil is not a symbol` when I try to run my test.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'CheckPrice', type: :request, js: true  do
  it "should create a new CheckPrice record when user clicks Check Price on topic page" do
    city = create :city
    hotel = create :hotel
    affiliate_link = create :affiliate_link

    visit '/hotel-bilboa-hotel'
    sleep 2
    click_button "Check Prices"
    response.should change(CheckPrice.count).by(1)
  end
end
```

When "Check Prices" is clicked, there is an event listener that triggers the new method in the checkprices_controller.

The error seems to occur on the last line `response.should change(CheckPrice.count).by(1)`. It looks like the method does not recognize the model CheckPrice. How do I reference the CheckPrice table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think you can use the `change` matcher like this on the response object. Try this:

```
expect {
  click_button "Check Prices"
}.to change{ CheckPrice.count }.by(1)
```

This makes more semantic sense, too, IMO.

See [this cheat sheet](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rspec/) for more examples.

Answer (score 17):

Semantic aside, to answer the original question (getting "nil is not a symbol") and help other people who might land here like I did: make sure to use curly brackets {} instead of parentheses ().

So (correct)

```
response.should change{CheckPrice.count}.by(1)
response.should change(CheckPrice, :count).by(1)
```

instead of (won't work, a mix of the 2 above)

```
response.should change(CheckPrice.count).by(1)
```

**Edit:**

Same answer with [recommended expect syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax)

So (correct)

```
expect{response}.to change{CheckPrice.count}.by(1)
expect{response}.to change(CheckPrice, :count).by(1)
```

instead of (won't work, a mix of the 2 above)

```
expect{response}.to change(CheckPrice.count).by(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be:

```
expect do
    click_button "Check Prices"
end.to change(CheckPrice, :count).by(1)
```

Which indicates that the output of the `count` method on `CheckPrice` is what is supposed to be changing.  When two parameters are passed to `change`, one is assumed to be a receiver, the other a symbol to send.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, the case is, as the other answers says, that both the methods `expect` and `change`, in this case, expect a block as parameter.

So, in rails, you can use either { } or `do` `end` syntaxes.